# DDD - is Payment Authorization a self contained subdomain or bounded context in payment sub-domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

In a particular domain which enables users to make payments to services, payment authorization is an integral part, but given that technically payment authorization can be designed as a standalone component that authorizes payments based on some pre-conditions and passed information.

In such case should payment authorization be a sub-domain(supporting domain) or just a bounded context in the payment sub-domain

Comment: According to "Domain Driven Design" by Eric Evan, that would depend on what the payment authorization service is or not the motivation for your project.